# Deleting images in a list

Tags: python

I've created a simple converter from images to pdf in pyhon. The idea was that after creating the pdf with all the images, the images get deleted. Here's the code:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
# from os.path import isfile, join

img_path = input('Entr the path with the images: ')
list = os.listdir(img_path)
# list = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, file))]

images = [
    Image.open(img_path + f)
    for f in list
]

print('Images used to create the pdf:\n' +'--> '+str(list))
print('The PDF will be saved here:\n' +'--> '+str(img_path))

pdf_path = img_path + "myPDF.pdf"
    
images[0].save(
    pdf_path, "PDF" , resolution=100.0, save_all=True, append_images=images[1:]
)

# not working part
print("Deleting images...\n")
for i in range(len(list)):
    if '.JPG' or '.NEF' in list[i]:
        os.remove(list[i])
        print(list[i]+' deleted')

print('--> PDF creato e salvato!\n Check: '+img_path)
```

The pdf is created correctly, however when the code is supposed to delete the images it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\vscode\PYTHON\imagestopdf.py", line 26, in <module>
    os.remove(list[i])
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Impossible to find the file specified: 'photo.JPG'
```

I can't understand where I did wrong. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Did you mean `os.remove(img_path  + list[i])`? Also, `'.JPG' or '.NEF' in list[i]` should be `'.JPG' in list[i] or '.NEF' in list[i]`

Comment: Also don't use `list` as a variable name, as you're overwriting the class.

Comment: no, i want to delete the photos in the folder, but not the pdf (thi is why I put the if statement)

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.path.join(img_path, list[i])` inside `os.remove`

I would highly recommend you use `pathlib` library instead of `os.path`

Instead of using `+` to join the path and file name use `os.path.join`

For pathlib simply

```py
import pathlib

img_path = pathlib.Path(img_path)

# to join path with file
img_path / "image.png"
# its that easy and this handles different file systems
```